# Repeated caucus badge notifications

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I keep getting notified I've received the caucus badge for voting in the 2019 moderator election:

[image: caucus]

I haven't actually seemed to receive it, but I definitely keep getting told I've earned it!

Comment: Smells like bot spirit ;)

Comment: You've earned the "Caucus" badge (Visit an election during any phase of an active election and have enough reputation to cast a vote).

Comment: See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325069/caucus-badge-award-multiple-times-for-one-election - **we've temporarily stopped awarding badges while we investigate this**.

Comment: Voter fraud! Get 'em!

Comment: @JoshCaswell: *removes vote for Josh Caswell*

Comment: @Shog9: I seem to have actually received the badge this time (+1 more notification, which is hopefully the last one)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be corrected now. The crux of the issue was a race condition that allowed one user to get qualifying user history entries for the badge twice - which then ruined it for everyone else.

Details here: [Caucus Badge award multiple times for one election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325069/caucus-badge-award-multiple-times-for-one-election/325074#325074)